# Sections switch place

Tags: html, css

im working on a website at the moment and i have a bit of a problem.
I have different tasks in blocks almost at the bottom of the site called 'werkzaamheden'. When I make them display:flex the site works good but the tasks mash up. when I make it display:block they dont go through eachother but they mess up the site. Bottom section is above task section now.

This is the link: http://www.ik-ben-zzp.nl/testsite/

So short: i need to have the task blocks inside the #middle section without overlapping.

IT GOES WRONG WHEN I SWITCH:

```
.taken
{
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

WITH:

```
.taken
{
    height:100%;
    display:block;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is what you wanted, just replace

```
.taken {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

And remove the CSS rules

```
.taak {
  /* float: left;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 50px; */
}
```

[image]